# How to pass Params in unit test cases?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I am writing unit test cases using jest and supertest in nodejs. I want to pass parameters to my api. How do I pass it?

I have tried passing it directly though the url but is there a way to pass it separately like we do for authorization?

This is how I have written

```
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../app');

describe('Get users', () => {
it('Positive flow', async () => {
let response = {"status" : "success"}
const res = await supertest(app).get('/users?offset=0&limit=25')
.set({ 'Authorization': 'Basic qwdfthjjdfgtsx='})
expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
expect(res.body).toEqual(response)
})
})
```

Here, I am sending offset and limit as params. I am adding it into the url and sending. Is there a way to send it like we send the body for post call or the way we are sending Authorization?

Comment: We don't know what parameters your API accepts, so it's hard to say. A GET request's body has no semantic meaning. If you're just asking whether you have to create the URL yourself: no, you can use `.query({ offset: 0 })`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wanted to use query the way you have mentioned. Thank you! Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?